# Craft site in subfolder of domain

Tags: assets, subfolder, alias

Unusual use-case - but I have a client with two websites they're merging into one. Their aim is to make the Craft 3 site (currently on its own top level domain) run in a /distribution sub folder.

I've managed to get this largely working by using the apache alias command:

```
Alias /distribution "/path/to/craftsite/web/"
```

and updating the site .env and config file to have the /distribution/ folder on the end of the `DEFAULT_SITE_URL`.

The site now loads but struggles loading CSS, JS and images as it's looking for these at the higher level than the /distribution folder which is aliased.

Is there an easy way to add a prefix to the path Craft is loading all the assets from?

Comment: Is this about the public assets or the cpresources for the backend?

Comment: Public assets so far (I may yet encounter issues with cpresources further through testing though...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of poking and prodding:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@assetBaseUrl' => '/distribution/assets/',
    '@assetBasePath' => '/path/to/the/assets/',
],
```

Added into the general.php file in config did the magic.

I still needed to alias the imager folder but all seems to be working well now in a sub-folder.